# Angular ngGrid with a detail view

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I would say that having a detail view for a grid is pretty standard, although I can't figure out for the life of me how I would accomplish this with ngGrid. I want a grid that I can expand a row and have it show the details of that row underneath.

Like the below grid:

[image]

How do I achieve this? Here is my code so far:

```
    vm.filterOptions = {
        filterText: '',
        useExternalFilter: false
    }

    var columns = [{field: 'oper_status', displayName: 'Status', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{serverUp: row.getProperty(col.field) == 1}"></div>'},
            {field: 'dns_name', displayName: 'Name'},
            {field: 'mgmt_ip_address', displayName: 'IP'},
            {field: 'model', displayName: 'Model'},
            {field: 'boot_version', displayName: 'Version'}];

    vm.gridOptions = {
        data: 'vm.devices',
        columnDefs: columns,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        selectedItems: vm.selectedItems,
        filterOptions: vm.filterOptions,
        afterSelectionChange: function() {
            vm.details = vm.selectedItems[0];
        }
    };
```

-html

```
<div ng-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: I usually do this without ng-grid, using pure angular and ng-collapse. Do you really need to use ng-grid?

Comment: Then I would need to worry about sorting, filtering, paging, grouping, and all the other bs that a 3rd party grid is SUPPOSED to give you.

Comment: Try trNgGrid which gives you all the features of ng-grid but is table based. ng-grid generates a lot of divs which have to be properly calculated and make it hard to show a detail view. With a table based grid this is much easier to achieve. http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/index.html

Comment: @mainguy Great alternative and much cleaner but still does not support detail tables.

Comment: @mainguy Actually it doesn't provide the most basic feature of ngGrid: virtualization. and AFAICT you can't create scrollable grids either, much less use features like pinning or sub-grids. Caveat: I am one of the authors of the ngGrid->uiGrid rewrite.

Comment: @c0bra Yeah, after digging in, I quickly ditched that effort and am building my own.

Comment: @Boone ui-grid is still in beta but something like this may work for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/GHenIsVu6eXhJ2dbZQFR?p=preview (docs here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid)